# MPI blocks and scatterv

Tags: c, mpi

I have a 2D matrix, lets say this matrix is the 4x6 matrix below:

```
 1  2  3  4  5  6
 7  8  9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24
```

and i want everyone of 4 processes to get a 2x3 submatrix and place it in a 4x5 buffer.

something like that:

```
0  0  0  0  0
0  1  2  3  0
0  7  8  9  0
0  0  0  0  0

0  0  0  0  0
0  4  5  6  0
0 10 11 12  0
0  0  0  0  0

0  0  0  0  0
0 13 14 15  0
0 19 20 21  0
0  0  0  0  0

0  0  0  0  0
0 16 17 18  0
0 22 23 24  0
0  0  0  0  0
```

the extra rows are not a problem because i can call MPI_Scatterv and point at the second row of the process buffer, but the extra columns make things complicated.
Is this possible using only MPI datatypes and one MPI_Scatterv call? If yes please give me some guidelines.

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
dim[0] = dim[1] = sqrt(numtasks);
periods[0] = periods[1] = 0;
MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dim, periods, 1, &commCart);
MPI_Comm_rank(commCart, &taskid);

NPROWS = dim[0];
NPCOLS = dim[1];
blockRows = ROWS / NPROWS;
blockColumns = COLS / NPCOLS;

if (taskid == MASTER) {
    for(i=0;i<ROWS*COLS;i++){
        global[i]=i;
    }
}

float* local;
local = malloc(blockRows * (blockColumns+2) * sizeof (float));

for (i = 0; i < blockRows * (blockColumns+2); i++) {
    local[0][i] = 0;
    local[1][i] = 0;
}
MPI_Datatype type, resizedtype,column;
int sizes[2]    = {ROWS,COLS};  
int subsizes[2] = {blockRows,blockColumns}; 
int starts[2]   = {0,0};  

MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, &type);  
MPI_Type_create_resized(type, 0, blockColumns*sizeof(float), &resizedtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&resizedtype);

int *counts = malloc(numworkers*sizeof(int));
int *displs = malloc(numworkers*sizeof(int));
for(i=0;i<numworkers;i++){
    counts[i] = 1;
}

int disp = 0;
for(i=0;i<NPROWS;i++){
    for(j=0;j<NPCOLS;j++){
        displs[i*dim[0] + j] = disp;
        disp++;
    }
    disp += (blockColumns-1)*dim[0];
}

MPI_Scatterv(global, counts, displs, resizedtype,      
        &local[0][blockColumns], blockRows*blockColumns, MPI_FLOAT,  
        MASTER, commCart);
```

Comment: Show us what you have done, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have guessed a bit as to how you actually want your code to work (for example, the way that local is currently defined and used as a 1D then a 2D array is not internally consistent). The main points to note are:

1. You need two datatypes: one to pick out the correct elements of global, the other to store to the correct elements of local.
2. It is easiest to resize the sendtype to be as large as an MPI_FLOAT so it can be placed at will; the displacements are therefore counted in numbers of floats.
3. On the receive side, you simply receive a single subarray - there is no need to resize it.

I haven't checked the code for generality but it seems to work for the specific case you have illustrated, i.e. a 4x6 matrix across a 2x2 decomposition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <mpi.h>

#define MASTER 0

#define ROWS 4
#define COLS 6

void main(void)
{
  int dim[2], periods[2], NPROWS, NPCOLS, blockRows, blockColumns;
  int numtasks, taskid, i, j;

  MPI_Comm commCart;

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
  dim[0] = dim[1] = sqrt(numtasks);
  periods[0] = periods[1] = 0;
  MPI_Cart_create(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 2, dim, periods, 1, &commCart);
  MPI_Comm_rank(commCart, &taskid);

  NPROWS = dim[0];
  NPCOLS = dim[1];
  blockRows = ROWS / NPROWS;
  blockColumns = COLS / NPCOLS;

  float* global;
  if (taskid == MASTER) {
    global = malloc(ROWS * COLS * sizeof (float));
    for(i=0;i<ROWS*COLS;i++){
      global[i]=i+1;
    }
  }

  float* local;
  local = malloc((blockRows+2) * (blockColumns+2) * sizeof (float));

  for (i = 0; i < (blockRows+2) * (blockColumns+2); i++) {
    local[i] = 0;
  }


  MPI_Datatype type, resizedtype,column;
  int sizes[2]    = {ROWS,COLS};
  int subsizes[2] = {blockRows,blockColumns};
  int starts[2]   = {0,0};

  MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, sizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_FLOAT, \
&type);
  MPI_Type_create_resized(type, 0, sizeof(float), &resizedtype);
  MPI_Type_commit(&resizedtype);

  int *counts = malloc(numtasks*sizeof(int));
  int *displs = malloc(numtasks*sizeof(int));
  for(i=0;i<numtasks;i++){
    counts[i] = 1;
  }

  int disp = 0;
  for(i=0;i<NPROWS;i++){
    for(j=0;j<NPCOLS;j++){
      disp = i*blockRows*COLS+j*blockColumns;
      displs[i*dim[0] + j] = disp;
    }
  }

  MPI_Datatype localtype;
  int localsizes[2]    = {blockRows+2,blockColumns+2};
  int localsubsizes[2] = {blockRows,blockColumns};
  int localstarts[2]   = {1,1};

  MPI_Type_create_subarray(2, localsizes, localsubsizes, localstarts, MPI_ORDER\
_C, MPI_FLOAT, &localtype);
  MPI_Type_commit(&localtype);


  MPI_Scatterv(global, counts, displs, resizedtype,
               &local[0], 1, localtype,
               MASTER, commCart);


  for (i=0; i < (blockRows+2)*(blockColumns+2); i++)
    {
      printf("rank %d: local[%d] = %f\n", taskid, i, local[i]);
    }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Here is the output - looks like what you want:

```
mpiexec -n 4 ./scatterv
rank 0: local[0] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[1] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[2] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[3] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[4] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[5] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[6] = 1.000000
rank 0: local[7] = 2.000000
rank 0: local[8] = 3.000000
rank 0: local[9] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[10] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[11] = 7.000000
rank 0: local[12] = 8.000000
rank 0: local[13] = 9.000000
rank 0: local[14] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[15] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[16] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[17] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[18] = 0.000000
rank 0: local[19] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[0] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[1] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[2] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[3] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[4] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[5] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[6] = 4.000000
rank 1: local[7] = 5.000000
rank 1: local[8] = 6.000000
rank 1: local[9] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[10] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[11] = 10.000000
rank 1: local[12] = 11.000000
rank 1: local[13] = 12.000000
rank 1: local[14] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[15] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[16] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[17] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[18] = 0.000000
rank 1: local[19] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[0] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[1] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[2] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[3] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[4] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[5] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[6] = 13.000000
rank 2: local[7] = 14.000000
rank 2: local[8] = 15.000000
rank 2: local[9] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[10] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[11] = 19.000000
rank 2: local[12] = 20.000000
rank 2: local[13] = 21.000000
rank 2: local[14] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[15] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[16] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[17] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[18] = 0.000000
rank 2: local[19] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[0] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[1] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[2] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[3] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[4] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[5] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[6] = 16.000000
rank 3: local[7] = 17.000000
rank 3: local[8] = 18.000000
rank 3: local[9] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[10] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[11] = 22.000000
rank 3: local[12] = 23.000000
rank 3: local[13] = 24.000000
rank 3: local[14] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[15] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[16] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[17] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[18] = 0.000000
rank 3: local[19] = 0.000000
```